# AVCaptureDevice.requestAccessForMediaType never pops up window and always return false

Tags: swift, swift2

I have some problem asking user for permission about camera. The `authorizationStatus` is always `NotDetermined`. When I tried to ask user for permission, `AVCaptureDevice.requestAccessForMediaType` never pops up a dialog and granted always returns `false`. I also can't find my app in settings - privacy - camera.

Can anyone help me with that? really appreciated

```
let availableCameraDevices = AVCaptureDevice.devicesWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    for device in availableCameraDevices{

        if (device.position == .Back){
            backCameraDevice = device
        }else{
            if (device.position == .Front){
                frontCameraDevice = device
            }
        }
    }

    let authorizationStatus = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatusForMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    switch authorizationStatus {
    case .NotDetermined:
        // permission dialog not yet presented, request authorization
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccessForMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo,
            completionHandler: { (granted:Bool) -> Void in
                if (granted == false) {
                    print(granted)
                }
                else {
                    print(granted)
                }
        })
    case .Authorized: break
        // go ahead
    case .Denied, .Restricted: break
        // the user explicitly denied camera usage or is not allowed to access the camera devices
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem solved. It seems that when we upgrade from iOS 8 to iOS 9, it has a new property in info.plist which is Bundle Display Name. Set the name to your product name if it is null, or the system will never know what app is asking for a permission

Comment: Simply genius! Thank you, @Jiatan Li. You saved my life.

Comment: For my Mac app, I needed to also make sure I had an AppIcon specified before the prompt would show!

Answer (score 1):

> If it's taking a long time to appear, then it sounds like you're not
>   running this on the main thread, which you should be. Also, if it has
>   prompted once before, it won't prompt again – the user has to go into
>   Settings and enable camera access.

from ALex [requestAccessForMediaType doesn't ask for permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28214262/requestaccessformediatype-doesnt-ask-for-permission)

Answer (score 0):

You should always be able to present the permission dialog when authorization status is `.NotDetermined`.

This and the fact that you can't find the app in privacy settings makes it sound like your phone is confused - so try resetting your privacy settings by going to `Settings.app > General > Reset` and hitting `Reset Location & Privacy`.

Comment: I tried to build a new app and run the same code, and it does triggers a system dialog to allow permission. However, it doesn't work on my older app... I'm not sure if there is anything I need to set in info.list or not. Also, I've tried resetting privacy several times, and every app on my iphone is requesting access to camera except mine....

Comment: Update: On a new app, when I run AVCaptureDevice.requestAccessForMediaType, it first pops up a system dialog to let user choose, and then returns granted. But in my app, AVCaptureDevice.requestAccessForMediaType just automatically denied the permission

Comment: Even after a reset? Maybe your app is doing something funny to UIKit

Comment: Same here... AVCaptureDevice.requestAccessForMediaType shows a dialog for AVMediaTypeVideo, but not for AVMediaTypeAudio. In a new app.