# Request camera permissions in macOS Mojave

Tags: swift, macos, camera, privacy, macos-mojave

Initializing an **AVCaptureDeviceInput** for a camera fails in macOS Mojave if the user has not granted permissions.
When trying to initialize, the system automatically presents the permission request dialog. There seems to be no way though to get notified of the user response.

- `+ (instancetype)deviceInputWithDevice:(AVCaptureDevice *)device 
                              error:(NSError * _Nullable *)outError;`
  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedeviceinput/1450880-deviceinputwithdevice

I'm looking for an analog way to get notified as with requesting audio permissions in:

- `func requestRecordPermission(_ response: @escaping PermissionBlock)`
  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616601-requestrecordpermission

The [Protecting the User's Privacy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy) guide does not outline any other methods for camera access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that the solution is actually analog to iOS by checking [`authorizationStatus(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624613-authorizationstatus) on **AVCaptureDevice** before initializing an **AVCaptureDeviceInput** from it.

And using [`requestAccess(for:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624584-requestaccess) to request the permission if needed.

An example for getting camera access:

```
let status = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video)

if status == .authorized {
  // connect to video device
  let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices(for: .video)
  ...
  return
}

if status == .denied {
  // show error
  return
}

AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { (accessGranted) in
  // handle result
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular order you did this in? Did you ever run into issue with the pop up not showing up if that status is `.notDetermined`?

Comment: @PauliusDragunas I added some sample code that worked for me - haven't had any issues with the popup not coming up.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28214262/requestaccessformediatype-doesnt-ask-for-permission?rq=1 seems related - are you invoking it on the main queue?

Comment: Whilst I have the `NSCameraUsageDescription` key (and `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` which I don't really need) in my app.plist, I don't ever get the pop-up, so it always fails.  The Status is returned as `.notDetermined` so I call `.requestAccess` while still inside the switch statement with the completionHandler.  (By the way, AVMediaType.video.rawValue == 'vide', not 'video'.)

Comment: It looks to me like the handler is never executed, as I've added some debugging print statements all over the place which never show up.

Answer (score 0):

Apple docs for presenting the dialog and capturing the response are found at: 
[Requesting Authorization for Media Capture on MacOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/requesting_authorization_for_media_capture_on_macos?language=objc)

It does require asynchronous handling of the dialog, so perhaps a combination of checking the authorization status with the approach presented in the docs would be helpful.

Steve